# Why isn't SQL Server 2008 R2 using all available RAM?

Tags: ram, sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb

We have an analytics database server running SQL 2008 R2 with 192 GB of physical RAM. However, we're noticing that during analytics process, the server only uses around 70 GB, but tempdb swells to 300+ GB. The current Maximum Memory is set to 2147483647 MB. The server is running Windows 2008 R2. Is there a way to make SQL Server use more RAM and less disk-based tempdb?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what is going on. We're currently using the Standard Edition of SQL Server 2008 R2, which, apparently, can only use a maximum of 64 GB of RAM.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685.aspx

Comment: That must be frustrating. Wouldn't it be nice if SQL Server at least logged a message to that effect? Something like: "This edition of SQL Server is not capable of utilizing more than 64 GB of RAM. For more information, please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685.aspx"